# Node js + Postgres, update Json column with SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, postgresql

I am making a db query upon hitting a POST API endpoint. The query needs to update the `Json` column in my `networks` table, which only has 3 columns (id, name, and json). I need to specifically update the **coreEssentials** array with another value, so I have been using the `set 'json' = ?` SQL query where I paste in the entire column with my changes in the specific field and it works (manually in the db). The only issues are, I need to do make a SQL call to `SELECT` the json column for a specific id first, (long story, but a backend application generates some data into the JSON (the coreEssentials key/object I need to update) then puts it into the data, then after I need to update).

I was doing this manually in my Postgresql GUI (DBbeaver) and my query simply looks like this:

```
update network set "json" = '{
  "uid": "randomUid",
  "etag": "randomEtag",
  "name": "randomNameAgain",
  "state": "PENDING",
  "Type": "ABC",
  "version": 1,
  "dealerId": "random_uuid",
  "Param": {
    "AreaId": 0,
    "AreaIdStr": "0.0.0.0",
    "DeadInterval": 0,
    "HelloInterval": 0
  },
  "networkData": {
    "tic": "311",
    "toe": "980",
    "tac": "201",
    "tac_id": "201",
    "timeZone": null
  },
  "production": false,
  "customerName": "random_name",
  "IPPool": "0.0.0.0/32",
  "customerEmail": "random@email.com",
  "coreEssentials": [ ],
  "deployment": "A"
}'
```

**coreEssentials** starts out as an Empty array but I need to set it to this:

```
[{
                "version": 1,
                "component": "purple",
                "instanceId": "1"
            },
            {
                "version": 1,
                "component": "gray",
                "instanceId": "1"
            },
            {
                "version": 1,
                "component": "blue",
                "instanceId": "1"
            } ]
```

I'm using a Node JS backend with pg-promise (Postgresql) library. Can anyone give me advice how to do this query?

Comment: Its is not clear why can't you just set `coreEssentials` with the array data, before serializing the JSON.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing... sorry, I 'm not a Javascript developer! :( thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just set coreEssentials array to the data object returned from the first SQL query like @vitaly-t suggested :D